# Irreducible representations and linear independence: a matrix irrep of dimension $d$ contains $d^2$ linearly independent matrices

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, clifford-algebras

I'm interested in the following statement:

> *an irreducible representation of dimension $d$ contains $d^2$ linearly independent matrices*

that can be found in H. C. Lee (1948), *On Clifford Algebras and Their Representations*:

> [image: Lee (1948). On Clifford Algebras and Their Representations]

Clifford algebras are defined in the following way: given $n$ objects $(u_\lambda)_{\lambda=1}^n$ verifying

$$u_\lambda u_\mu + u_\mu u_\lambda=2\delta_{\lambda\mu}\,,\quad 1\le\lambda,\mu\le n\,,$$

their Clifford algebra is the linear combinations of all their (finite) products (this should be standard, as far as I know). The author is using a generic *algebraically closed* field with characteristic $\ne 2$, but sticking to complex matrices would be more than fine [edit: initially I forgot the closure request, so I have to apologize].

It seems to me that what, in today's literature, is known as [Burnside's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_theorem) is a different statement (maybe implying the one I'm interested in, but not in a way that can be obvious to me).

I also took a look at the author's reference, van der Waerden, and found this *Theorem of Burnside*:

> *In an absolutely irreducible semigroup of matrices of $n$-th degree there are exactly $n^2$ linearly independent matrices*

but then the text is invoking several notions, such as of "hypercomplex systems", which I'm not familiar with.

So my question is: is there some simple set of hypotheses under which the statement is true?, if yes, is there a clean and elementary proof of it?

My level of understanding is quite basic, I'm afraid; I know just a bit of representation theory for finite groups, no more than what is covered in the first three chapters of Simon's book, [*] so when we're dealing with a finite-dimensional algebra representation, I just think of it as a unital algebra homomorphism to a complex matrix algebra, and of its reducibility/irreducibility just by borrowing the corresponding notion for finite groups.

---

[*] indeed, I've been struggling with Simon's fourth chapter, the one on Clifford groups and algebras, precisely because I'm not sure I correctly got his definitions. He seems to be working directly with matrices, in which case imho there is an ambiguity with the order of the group for at least some odd $n$.

Answer (score 4):

This seems like a very old-fashioned book; you'd likely be off reading something more modern. Here is a precise statement: if $A$ is an associative algebra over an algebraically closed field $k$ (this hypothesis cannot be dropped) and $M$ is an irreducible representation / [simple module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_module) over $A$ of dimension $n$, with action map

$$\rho : A \to \text{End}_k(M) \cong M_n(k)$$

then $\rho$ is surjective, so its image is all of $M_n(k)$ and hence has dimension $n^2$. This follows from [Schur's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_lemma) together with the [Jacobson density theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_density_theorem). I am not aware of Burnside's name being attached to this but I suppose it wouldn't be surprising. It can also be deduced from the [Artin-Wedderburn theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedderburn%E2%80%93Artin_theorem) (applied to the image of $A$, but here one has to know that two different definitions of "semisimple" for a ring coincide).

If $k$ isn't algebraically closed then the statement is instead that the image of $\rho$ is $\text{End}_D(M)$ where $D = \text{End}_A(M)$ is the division ring of $A$-endomorphisms of $M$, and this can have dimension not a square over $k$; for example if $k = \mathbb{R}$ we could have $D = \mathbb{C}$ which has dimension $2$, and matrix rings over $\mathbb{C}$ would have dimension twice a square over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The author requires the field to be closed, so I will edit my question accordingly. Unfortunately I'm ok with Schur's lemmas, but I've not studied either the Jacobson or the Artin-Weddenburn theorem; could you please suggest me a reference (a textbook or some lecture notes)?, please as simple as it can be…

Comment: @atlantropa: I haven't studied it myself but probably Curtis and Reiner will have everything you could ask for: https://www.amazon.com/Representation-Associative-Algebras-Chelsea-Publishing/dp/0821840665

Comment: @atlantropa: ah, and I also wrote a blog post proving the Artin-Wedderburn theorem in what I believe is more or less the standard way here (you can ignore most of the post and just skip to the proof): https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/01/25/a-first-blog-post-on-noncommutative-rings/